# setState from parent widget doesn't update value for child

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a StatefulWidget where there is a ListView holding several childs widget.

One of the child is a `GridView` containing some items.

What I would want to achieve is to rebuild this `GridView` child when a button is pressed from the Parent widget. The button is located in the `bottomNavigationBar` in the Parent widget.

However, when I pressed the button, it should go to the `_resetFilter()` method, which works. But the `setState()` doesn't seem to update the GridView `build()` method inside Child widget.

```dart
class ParentState extends State<Parent> {

  // removed for brevity

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _resetFilter();
                  },
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(...), // this works
                          Column(...),
                          Container(...), // this works
                          Container( 
                            child: GridView.count(
                              // ...
                              children:
                                  List.generate(oriSkills.length, (int i) {

                                bool isSkillExist = false;

                                if (_selectedSkills.contains(rc.titleCase)) {
                                  isSkillExist = true;
                                } else {
                                  isSkillExist = false;
                                }
                                return Child( // this doesn't work
                                  id: oriSkills[i]['id'],
                                  name: oriSkills[i]['description'],
                                  skillSelect: isSkillExist, // this boolean showed correct value from the above logic
                                  onChange: onSkillChange,
                                );
                              }),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _resetFilter() {
    setState(() {
      _theValue = 0.0;
      searchC.text = "";
      _selectedSkills = []; // this is the variable that I'd like the GridView to recreate from.
    });
  }
}
```

I tried to print one of the field name inside Child widget, but it always showing the old value instead of the new one.

Even after presing the button, it does passing correct value to `ChildState`.

```dart
class ChildState extends State<Child> {
  final String name;
  final MyCallbackFunction onChange;
  bool skillSelect;
  double size = 60.0;

  ChildState({this.name, this.skillSelect, this.onChange});

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void setSkillLevel() {
    setState(() {
      if (skillSelect) {
        skillSelect = false;
        onChange(name, false);
      } else {
        skillSelect = true;
        onChange(name, true);
      }
    });
  }

  Color _jobSkillSelect(bool select) {
    print(select); // always print old state instead of new state
    return select ? Color(MyColor.skillLvlOne) : Color(MyColor.skillDefault);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      InkResponse(
          onTap: setSkillLevel,
          child: Container(
            height: size,
            width: size,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(_jobSkillSelect(skillSelect), BlendMode.color),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    ]));
  }
}
```

How can I update the Child widget to have the updated value from the Parent widget after reset button is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to pass the values to the actual Child class. **Not** to its state.
The class is whats rebuilding once your parent rebuilds. So the new values will be reflected.

So your `Child` implementation should look something like this (don't forget to replace the `onChange` Type to your custom Function.

```
class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final Function(void) onChange;
  final bool skillSelect;
  final double size;
  final Function(bool) onSkillLevelChanged;

  const Child({Key key, this.name, this.onChange, this.skillSelect, this.size, this.onSkillLevelChanged}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChildState createState() => _ChildState();
}

class _ChildState extends State<Child> {
  Color _jobSkillSelect(bool select) {
    print(select); // always print old state instead of new state
    return select ? Color(MyColor.skillLvlOne) : Color(MyColor.skillDefault);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          InkResponse(
              onTap: () {
                if (widget.onSkillLevelChanged != null) {
                  widget.onSkillLevelChanged(!widget.skillSelect);
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                height: widget.size,
                width: widget.size,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(_jobSkillSelect(widget.skillSelect), BlendMode.color),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this case the Child ist not responsible anymore for managing its `skillSelect` property. It simply calls a `Function` on its parent. The parent then builds with a new skillSelect boolean.

So you might use this child like this:

```
return Child( // this doesn't work
   id: oriSkills[i]['id'],
   name: oriSkills[i]['description'],
   skillSelect: oriSkills[i]['isSkillExist'], 
   onChange: onSkillChange,
   onSkillLevelChanged: (newSkillLevel) {
      setState(() {
         oriSkills[i]['isSkillExist'] = newSkillLevel;
      });
   },
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your idea. But did you happen to write [this](https://i.imgur.com/BnAxzQv.jpg) answer but then deleted/edited it? Can't find the full text but the solution inside the notification helped me solve it :sweat_smile: So I'm not sure if your answer above should be accepted or not lol.

Comment: Well yes I have edited it :) What error do you get with the current solution? We should fix that for people that are coming across this question in the future :)

Comment: I didn't get any error or anything. It's just not what I was looking for. I was trying to make `widget.skillSelect` to react with the new value from its parent widget. So I initialize it in the `initState` of the Child widget, and everything works now thanks to you. If you would like to re-edit your solution with the old answer, I'd gladly accept it as an answer :) Also, sorry for the confusion in the question. I'm just pretty new at Flutter's object lifecycle.

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow you. If you initialize a value in the child widgets initState() it will not be changed when the parent tree rebuilds. Anyways. I am not sure what the contents were before...

Comment: But it did in my case. I'll re-edit my question with some more codes later to give more context on this.